# Unable to print Base64 encoded string

Tags: java, eclipse, base64

Can someone explains to me why the 2nd println statement below is not printing anything? Even if I use the encodeToString() method instead of the encode() method, I still can't print the Base64 encoded string. The encoded string is not empty as I can verify using its length() method. I tried a different file, a binary one, and the problem is still there.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D:\\config.properties"));
            System.out.println(content.length); // correctly prints the length
            byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(content);
            System.out.println(new String(encoded)); // prints nothing
            content = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
            System.out.println(new String(content)); // prints original content
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

This problem only exists when I run the program in Eclipse. When I run it from the command prompt, the Base64 encoded string can be printed out.

Comment: Yes, I meant the 2nd. I have corrected.

Comment: Can't reproduce, works for me. What is the content of the `config.properties` file? Also what Java version are you using?

Comment: I run this in Eclipse version 2018-09 (4.9.0), using its in-build 1.8 compiler.

Comment: I tried a different text file and this time it does print the Base64 encoded string. Very strange. I originally tried with a PDF file and got the same problem.

Comment: Looks like this is a problem inside Eclipse only. From the command prompt, when I run the same program using the Oracle JDK, it printed out the Base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

When new String(encoded) is called to print the encoded byte array, nothing is printed to the console. This is because the new String(byte[]) constructor expects the byte array to be a valid character encoding, but the encoded byte array is **not necessarily** a valid character encoding. Instead of using new String(encoded), you can use Arrays.toString(encoded) or Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(content) to print the encoded byte array.

If this works in one environment and not the other there might be different default encodings in place. Check your environment settings.
File encoding could be set like this:

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
```